Laravel mongodb save data mantaining values types
I need to save some data for cache purposes. The thing is that this data may contain std objects or associative arrays. The "create" method saves all as associative array, so when I need this cached data I'm running in issues because trying to read properties as object on associative arrays and viceversa.
An example:
CachedData::create([
   'type' => 'pr',
   'stage' => 'fetching',
   'data' => [
       'name' => 'pr_name',
       'history' => [
            0 => {            //This is a representation of std object
                 +"price" => 10.00,
                 +"datetime" => "2023-10-22 01:32:00"
            }
       ]
   ]
]) 

When I get data the result is:
[
   'name' => 'pr_name'
   'history' => [      
      0 => [             //Array instead of object
          'price' => 10.00,
          'datetime' => "2023-10-22 01:32:00"
      ]
   ]
]

Data is always variable. So is there a way to keep value type the same as when it was saved?

I found the way. Just serialize data before saving:
CachedData::create(['data' => serialize($data)]);

Then you can unserialize when you need it:
unserialize(CachedData::get()->data);

It will mantain your object as it was when it was saved
